# Complie Error when I try to add GooglePlacesPicker to Swift Project

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to add GooglePlacesPicker to my application. I Added the following line to my podfile:

```
pod 'GooglePlacesPicker'
```

and ran:

```
pod install
```

Which installed the pod to my project. But when I try to build the project after adding GooglePlacesPicker pod to my project, I get:

```
Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'placeTextFieldDidChange()' that is not exposed to Objective-C
Add '@objc' to expose this instance method to Objective-C
```

This error seems to exist in one of Google's files: AlertSelectPlaceController.swift. To be clear, this is NOT a file that I created, it seems to have come with the pod.

So I could hit the "Fix" button and add the @objc flag, but its a locked file and I really dont want to be messing around with Google's code (I figure it is pretty good).

I tried updating my API keys based on another StackOverflow answer, but no luck...

Any ideas?

EDIT: This is the function that is bombing out for me:

[image]

Comment: I think you have installed objective c pods. Try adding bridging header

Comment: Can you show your pod file?

Comment: btw, if you fix the error by including @objc, it would not hurt google's code :)